# AssertionError: None is not callable

Tags: python, twisted

I'm in the process of learning how to program in twisted, and going through Dave Peticolas' tutorial (http://krondo.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/twisted-intro.html). I'm trying to solve the suggested exercise at the end of Part 3 - having multiple independent countdowns going on countdown.py. Here is my code, and the error I'm getting:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class countdown(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.timer = 0

    def count(self, timer):
        if self.timer == 0:
            reactor.stop()
        else:
            print self.timer, '...'
            self.timer -= 1
            reactor.callLater(1, self.count)


from twisted.internet import reactor

obj = countdown()
obj.timer = 10
reactor.callWhenRunning(obj.count(obj.timer))

print 'starting...'
reactor.run()
print 'stopped.'
```

When executed:

```
$ ./countdown.py
10 ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./countdown.py", line 21, in <module>
    reactor.callWhenRunning(obj.count(obj.timer))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 666, in callWhenRunning
    _callable, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 645, in addSystemEventTrigger
    assert callable(_f), "%s is not callable" % _f
AssertionError: None is not callable
```

I assume I'm not doing something properly in leveraging an object variable; though I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling you callable **before passing it in**. The returned result of the `obj.count()` call is not callable.

You need to pass in the method, not the result of calling it:

```
reactor.callWhenRunning(obj.count, (obj.timer,))
```

The positional arguments for your method (here just `obj.timer`) should be given as a separate tuple.

At closer inspection, you don't even need to pass in `obj.timer` as an argument. You can just access it on `self` after all, there is no need to pass it in separately:

```
class countdown(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.timer = 0

    def count(self):
        if self.timer == 0:
            reactor.stop()
        else:
            print self.timer, '...'
            self.timer -= 1
            reactor.callLater(1, self.count)
```

and adjust your `callWhenRunning()` call accordingly:

```
reactor.callWhenRunning(obj.count)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That solves my issue. I was hoping to have two separate objects for timers; though that just causes the reactor to stop once the first timer times out. What's the best way of accomplishing this?